# Moving instances on vertices along individual paths

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, instances

I cannot figure out how to move my instances individually. They are placed on each vertex of an icosphere. The path they should move along has that vertex as a starting point (eventually they end on vertices of another icosphere).
I thought that a realize instances would work, I later found out that "translate instances" kind of does the trick.

Here's what I came up with (with the help of @Leander).

[imgur.com/a/aVFl3mJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2wJT.jpg)

Though I can't understand why my spheres spread around the original sphere. Then they follow the intended path and that makes me happy.

here's the blend [fileport.io/qvYqV9A8Yrtd](https://fileport.io/qvYqV9A8Yrtd)

Comment: If the paths are straight lines, you don't need the paths. Is that a thought worth having?

Comment: actually no I already set them up as bezier curves and right now am trying to find a shape I like

Comment: just a hint: if you provide your blend file - you will attract more people (and the lazy ones like me, who don't want to recreate your node tree manually). Keep in mind: these people use their spare time to answer your questions for free, so you should make it as easy as can be for them to answer them.

Comment: and pleeease don't write in all caps because this might be considered as rude. thx.

Comment: ok thanks Chris!
here's the blend
https://fileport.io/qvYqV9A8Yrtd

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: ok done, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a position node then a vector math subtract node on the link between your sample curve and translate instances nodes (assuming that's what your question is) [image]